How can I achieve the "Run in Konsole" action using the Enter key on the keyboard?
When hitting enter (or double-clicking) an executable shell script (a ".sh" file, for instance), it would be nice if this would launch the script inside a console window.
I am using the Dolphin file manager, and KDE with Debian 11. While there are many ways to open, launch, and execute scripts, but nothing that does this one simple thing.
When tapping enter on an executable shell script, the box below is displayed:


"Open" will incorrectly "open the script" using the console app
(result is that the console window opens, but nothing happens)
"Execute" will correctly run the script
(result is that the script runs, but the console window never opens, and output is not shown unless it is redirected to a file)

When right-clicking an executable script, the following menu is shown:


"Open with Konsole" will incorrectly "open the script" using the console app
(result is that the console window opens, but nothing happens)
"Run in Konsole" is perfect!
(script is both opened AND run inside a new console window, and output is shown on-screen)

The question is: How can I achieve the "Run in Konsole" action using the Enter key on the keyboard?
That's the real problem here: using the mouse to right-click and pick over and over is tiresome.
Apparently, this used to be possible in the Thunar file manager until recently (the feature was removed). Most other threads I have found on this topic all require the right-mouse-button:

How to ensure an executable script runs upon double clicking it?
How to automatically open terminal window when I click a script?

Any advice or guidance is appreciated.
